# Use of #pragma pack on a class

Tags: c++, class, pragma

Can we use #pragma pack() before a class?

What is the significance of pragma here?  I know it is used for giving information to compiler regarding implementation, but what if we use it with a class?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It has the **exact** same effect on a class as it does on a struct, affecting the alignment of data members.

Actually using it on a class is very unusual and almost always a mistake.  The layout of a C++ class object is heavily implementation defined.  A C++ compiler usually makes an effort to optimize that layout, dropping the v-table pointer when it can.  And potentially adding one when the class uses multiple inheritance.  So a minor change to the class declaration, like making a method *virtual* or adding a base class can significantly alter the object layout.  This will then of course break the code that depends on that pragma.  Like an object serialized to a binary file won't deserialize properly anymore.  In general a bad practice too but happens all the time anyway.  Don't use it.